# While extracting data from JsonPath object getting a null

Tags: json, testng, rest-assured, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

While extracting data from JsonPath object getting a null,below is the json response data

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "header": {
        "headerAttributes": {}
    },
    "errors": [],
    "payload": {
        "totalCount": 0,
        "returnTerms": []
    }
}
```

java method for extracting value from "totalCount"

```
public void getjsonValue() {
        JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
        System.out.println(jsonPathEvaluator.get("$['payload']['totalCount']"));
}
```

Comment: try System.out.println(jsonPathEvaluator.get("${['payload']['totalCount']}"));

Comment: It didn't worked getting an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Answer (score 5):

I hope this is the last time I answer the question about JsonPath of rest-assured. People often get confused JsonPath rest-assured with JsonPath jayway, then use wrong syntax.

The right syntax is:

```
jsonPathEvaluator.get("payload.totalCount")
```